# My cat wakes me up at night pawing at my door

Tags: cats, scratching

My cat paws at my door at night and wakes me up. I know the easy thing to do is leave the door open but I can't sleep with it open.is there a way to keep her from scratching at my door?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

You need to ignore it. If necessary buy ear plugs. She needs to learn that scratching the door does not yield anything.

Be consequent. Even opening the door once will teach her that if she scratches the door will open so she will try again. Be patient. Never open the door, don't talk through the closed door, etc. just completely ignore it.

I'd also make sure their bowls are full. Our cats have unrestricted access to food: as soon as I see an empty bowl I fill it up. This is optimal for cats without eating disorder.

To help it you could buy some cat deterrent spray (smells of something the cat does not like) which you can spray on the door. This can help prevent further scratching of the door.

Finally, I'd place one on each side of these of your door:

[http://www.amazon.com/SmartCat-3832-Ultimate-Scratching-Post/dp/B000634MH8/ref=zg_bs_2975247011_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000634MH8)

Answer (score 2):

You say ...

> the easy thing to do is leave the door open

I'm saying, it's not only the easy thing, it's the only thing!  Those of us fortunate to have cats in our home give up some things...one of those *things* is the right to keep an inside door closed (when a person is behind it)...ever.

Regardless of this, here are some things that may help you...

1. Get an open pet door for the door to your room.  Your kitty can come and go as she please.
2. If you want no opening to the outside of your room at night, spend some extra money to get a pet door that responds to a signal in your cat's collar (meaning you would have to get your cat to wear a collar) and the system opens the pet door when the cat is in close vicinity.   IMPORTANT:  If you live in an apartment, you will need to buy a second door to cut out the pet door and store the original door.  When you leave the apt, put on the original door so you don't get charged.
3. Another option is setting up a can of "air" just outside your bedroom door.  (see link).  This item detects movement and sprays a small amount of air to startle the cat.  The website says the air is nontoxic, odor free, and harmless to your kitty.

> [http://www.amazon.com/Ssscat-PDT00-13914-SSSCAT-Cat-Training/dp/B000RIA95G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RIA95G)

I have never tried this method before, but I have heard behaviorists recommend it.  However, I have a very smart cat.  I can see her figuring out how to get around it or knocking it down.

4. I have also seen people open their bedroom door just enough for the cat to get through and hang a long cloth over the opening so they can still have privacy.

I wish you and your kitty the best!